# How to create master data source in tableau desktop version 9.3?

Tags: report, tableau-api

I have **5 tde** which includes data for **last 5 years**. I am trying to create a **single view or master data source** based on these 5 tde. If I want to show data of last 5 years together how can I do this by using these 5 tdes. I am trying to append the data by using option '**Append data from file**' but it prompts '**0 rows added successfully**'. I just want to create a view/ master data source which will hold data for all 5 years.

Comment: is your original data source in one table/file or five? Build extracts from original data, not from other extracts.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Can you please explain me why we can't build extract from other extracts and why there is need to build extract from original table only or how this cannot be a lucrative way. My original data source is in one table but I am trying to build extracts based on 5 tde which consist data for 5 years to optimise performance.

Comment: An extract (TDE) is a copy of SOME of the data in an original source. You determine what to include in the copy by applying filters to the extracts to select just the rows you want, hiding fields to select just the columns you want, and possibly aggregating to the visible (non hidden) dimensions to pre-aggregate the data. An extract itself doesn't contain most of the metadata, nor the reference to the original source. That's in the data source (TDS). Keeping the data source info is valuable, allows you to regenerate the extract if needed, keeps calculated field definitions etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I got what I have to do.